# Unable to load HTML file of a Dialog on menu of Google Sheets with Google Apps Script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, web-applications, bootstrap-5

I've been unable to load the HTML file called `addSupermarket.html` into the dialog which pops up. The idea is that main.html which contains the pop-up dialog's HTML has tabs. And the tabs won't switch and also don't load the respective html files for the tabs.

This file is called `loadForm.gs` and it loads the menu.

```
function loadMainForm() {
  const htmlServ = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile("main");
  const html = htmlServ.evaluate();
  const ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  html.setWidth(850).setHeight(600);
  ui.showModalDialog(html, "Add Supermarket");
}

function createMenu() {
   SpreadsheetApp.getUi().createMenu("Utilities")
     .addItem("Add new Supermarket", "loadMainForm")
     .addToUi();
}

function onOpen() {
  createMenu();
}
```

This is what `main.html` looks like. It is the actual HTML of the dialog but I want to load the HTML of the tab `addSupermarkets.html` into the tab called *Add Supermarket*.

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-1BmE4kWBq78iYhFldvKuhfTAU6auU8tT94WrHftjDbrCEXSU1oBoqyl2QvZ6jIW3" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <title>Hello, world!</title>
    <style>
      .nav-link {
        cursor:pointer;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
      <li class="nav-item">
        <div class="nav-link active" id="search-link">Search</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <div class="nav-link" id="add-supermarket-link">Add Supermarket</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
    <div class="container">
      <div id="app"></div>

    </div>

    <!-- Optional JavaScript; choose one of the two! -->

    <!-- Option 1: Bootstrap Bundle with Popper -->
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-ka7Sk0Gln4gmtz2MlQnikT1wXgYsOg+OMhuP+IlRH9sENBO0LRn5q+8nbTov4+1p" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

    <!-- Option 2: Separate Popper and Bootstrap JS -->

    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@popperjs/core@2.10.2/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-7+zCNj/IqJ95wo16oMtfsKbZ9ccEh31eOz1HGyDuCQ6wgnyJNSYdrPa03rtR1zdB" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-QJHtvGhmr9XOIpI6YVutG+2QOK9T+ZnN4kzFN1RtK3zEFEIsxhlmWl5/YESvpZ13" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

  <script>

    function loadAddSupermarketView() {
      google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(function(html) {
        document.getElementById("app").innerHTML = html;
      }).loadAddSupermarketView();
    }
    document.getElementById("add-supermarket-link").addEventListener("click", loadAddSupermarketView);

  </script>

  </body>
</html>
```

`addsupermarket.html` looks like this right now, it just has an H1 text as a placeholder.

```
<h1Add Supermarket</h1>
```

This is `loadAddSupermarket.gs`

```
function loadPartialHTML_(partial) {
  const htmlServ = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile(partial);
  return htmlServ.evaluate.getContent();
}

function loadAddSupermarketView() {
  return loadPartialHTML_("addSupermarket");
}
```

This is the dialog that shows up. [image: Pop up Dialog with blank contents]

Where have I gone wrong? Why can I not load the HTML into the file?

Comment: It's there a typo in `<h1Add Supermarket</h1> `, a `>` is missing the opening h1 tag. Is this typo on file or was just typing mistake only done here? Does the web-browser console or the Google Apps Script execution logs show any error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried to replicate your code and found some issues:

1. Incorrect file extension for `loadForm.html` and `loadAddSupermarket.html`, File contains Apps Script method, you should use `.gs` file extension instead
2. You have unnecessary imports in your HTML file. `nav-bar` action does not need Popper.js, it requires JQuery and JQuery is not imported in your HTML, this causes the other tab not to be clickable.
3. In your `loadAddSupermarket.gs` file, addSupermarket does not match any file in your file list. Apps Script is case sensitive when it comes to file names. Rename your `addsupermarket.html` with `addSupermarket.html`
4. In the `htmlServ.evaluate.getContent();` of `loadPartialHTML_(partial)` function. This will produce an error as script can't find `evaluate` property in the HtmlTemplate. I think you missed to add `()` next to it.
5. The items under `<li>` starts with `<div>` but ends with `</a>`. You should use   instead.

Here I refactor your code and was able to get the correct output for Add Supermarket tab.

**main.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
    <li class="nav-link active"><a data-toggle="tab" href="#search" id="search-link">Search</a></li>
    <li class="nav-link"><a data-toggle="tab" href="#addsupermarket" id="add-supermarket-link">Add Supermarket</a></li>
  </ul>
  <div class="tab-content">
    <div id="search" class="tab-pane fade in active"></div>
    <div id="addsupermarket" class="tab-pane fade"></div>
  </div>

  <script>
    function loadAddSupermarketView() {
      google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(function(html) {
        document.getElementById("addsupermarket").innerHTML = html;
      }).loadAddSupermarketView();
    }
    document.getElementById("add-supermarket-link").addEventListener("click", loadAddSupermarketView);
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

**addSupermarket.html**

```
<h1>Add Supermarket</h1>
```

**loadform.gs**

```
function loadMainForm() {
  const htmlServ = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile("main");
  const html = htmlServ.evaluate();
  const ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  html.setWidth(850).setHeight(600);
  ui.showModalDialog(html, "Add Supermarket");
}

function createMenu() {
   SpreadsheetApp.getUi().createMenu("Utilities")
     .addItem("Add new Supermarket", "loadMainForm")
     .addToUi();
}

function onOpen() {
  createMenu();
}
```

**loadAddSupermarket.gs**

```
function loadPartialHTML_(partial) {
  const htmlServ = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile(partial);
  return htmlServ.evaluate().getContent();
}

function loadAddSupermarketView() {
  return loadPartialHTML_("addSupermarket");
}
```

**Output:**

[image]

### References:

- [Bootstrap - components requiring Javascript](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/getting-started/introduction/#js)
- [HTMLTemplate.evaluate()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/html/html-template#evaluate)

Comment: You've included functions `function loadPartialHTML_(partial)` and `function loadAddSupermarketView()` in both "loadAddSupermarket.gs" and "loadform.gs". Was that deliberate? I tested excluding it from "loadform.gs" and things still work as expected.

Comment: For the benefit of this learner... you remarked "_The script can't find evaluate property, because it is a method. You should enclosed it with ()_." Took me a while to comprehend this. As I understand it, you're saying it should be `return htmlServ.evaluate().getContent()` compared to `return htmlServ.evaluate.getContent()`.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions! I've implemented it and it works, however I've noticed that the second tab's HTML (addSupermarket.html) doesn't load automatically (takes a few seconds). Any way to add a progress bar before the dialog pops up so that as soon as the dialog does show up, it contains everything loaded and ready to use.

Comment: @Tedinoz  - Thank you for pointing out. I forgot to removed the `loadPartialHTML()` and `loadAddSupermarketView()` in loadform.gs. I used that for testing so that all Apps Script related code are in one file.  I updated my answer and remove those function.

Comment: @krispo.uke _Moreover, if I wanted to load the HTML straight into the dialog - how might I approach this?_ `addSupermarket.html` contains the HTML that appears on the "Add Supermarket" tab. If you wanted to pursue this further, I suggest that you research, test and then ask a new question if/when you have a specific problem.

Comment: @krispo.uke - I tried it on my end and the script was able to load the 2nd tab in less than 1 sec. Have you added anything in the `addSupermarket.html`? Also, I noticed that some of your inquiries are not related to the issue of your post, `(Unable to load HTML file in Dialog box` and `Tabs not switching)`. I would suggest you to create another question including a detailed explanation on what you are trying to achieve.  This is to avoid confusion to other user and gives you a better chance of getting good answers.

Comment: Also, If this answered your question, please click the accept button on the left (check icon).  By doing so, other people in the community, who may have the same concern as you, will know that theirs can be resolved.  If the accept button is unavailable to you, feel free to tell me. [how to accept answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer)